# Insert into two tables with no relationships

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning LINQ and was wondering how can I `INSERT` into two different tables with no relationship on one click using LINQ. Is it even possible?

I am adding into one table like this. How can I add into the second table as well?

Second Table,

> GenreId
>
> Name
>
> Description

Code,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Artist artist)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      _db.Artists.Add(artist);
      _db.Genres.Add(new Genre { GenreId = 1, Name = "Some Genre", Description = "Trying to add second table" }); // how can i add the genre object here
      _db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = artist.ArtistId });
   }

   return View(artist);
}
```

Note that my `View` is strongly typed to `Artist` class.

My View,

```
@model EntityFrameWorkDBFirst.Models.Artist


@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.Genres) // how to get this working
```

My Model Class,

```
public partial class Artist
{
    public Artist()
    {
        this.Albums = new HashSet<Album>();
        this.Genres = new HashSet<Genre>();
    }

    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Tuple related suggestion didn't work. Maybe I am missing something.

```
@model Tuple<EntityFrameWorkDBFirst.Models.Artist, EntityFrameWorkDBFirst.Models.Genre>

    <legend>Create a Artist</legend>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item1.Name)

    <h2>Genre</h2>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item2.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item2.Name)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Artist artist, Genre genre)
{


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Artists.Add(artist);
        _db.Genres.Add(genre);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = artist.ArtistId });
    }
    return View(artist);

}
```

Comment: I guess, you are asking how can you make a `View` strongly typed and get the data from `View` for both tables and not necessarily how to insert into 2 tables, right?

Comment: yes kind of, but its not necessary that i make my `View` strongly typed. My main concern is how do I insert it into two tables. Which I can now using the below answer, but then what happens to my `View`?

Comment: You could use Tuple<Artist, Genre> as your Model. It is still strongly typed, but provides one object of each class.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster, could you please provide a sample to refer.

Comment: This typically calls for a view model that contains all data you want to display/modify in the view. In the controller (or preferably an underlying service method) you dissect the view model into the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed domain model and view model.

It's big mistake, you should work only with viewmodel on view.

You should create view model:

```
public class CreateArtistViewModel
{
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public int? Genres { get; set; } // if you provide chooser for user
    public string GenresName { get; set; } // if user can enter new genre
    public string GenresDecription { get; set; } // if user can enter new genre

    public IList<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

in the post action you should check view model and create artist and genre if user create new gener.

Comment: what about the `View` since it is strong typed. As in how can i add data from front end for both Classes.